# Issue with using function within int main, uninitialized memory, uninitialized local variable

Tags: c

I've got a bit of an issue, I'm learning the use of functions in C. I tried using functions to implement them into my code, however, I keep getting errors initialized memory as well as an initialized local variable.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getItemPrice(int applePrice, int orangePrice, int pearPrice);
int displayMenu(int applePrice, int orangePrice, int pearPrice);
int withinBudget(int budget, char purchase, int applePrice, int orangePrice, int pearPrice);
int purchaseItem(int budget, char purchase, int applePrice, int orangePrice, int pearPrice);

int main()
{
    
    int orangePrice, applePrice, pearPrice, budget, calculation, items;     
    char input;                                                 
    printf("*****************\n");
    printf("Item prefixes\n");
    printf("A: Apple\n");
    printf("O: Orange\n");
    printf("P: Pear\n");
    printf("*****************\n\n");

    
    printf("***************\n");
    printf("*** MyStore ***\n");
    printf("***************\n\n");
    
    printf("**** SHOPKEEPER PANEL ****\n");

    getItemPrice(applePrice, orangePrice, pearPrice);

    displayMenu(applePrice, orangePrice, pearPrice);
    
    printf("**** Customer menu ****\n");
    printf("Please enter your budget: \x9C");
    scanf_s("%d", &budget);                                     // User is being prompted to enter budget for their purchases
    printf("Please enter the item you would like to purchase using the item Prefix: ");
    scanf_s(" %c", &input, 1);                                  // User is being prompted to enter the item prefix to purchase items
    printf("\n\n");


    if (input == 'A') {
        items = applePrice;              // Will make input 'A' = to the price of apples.
    }
    else if (input == 'O') {
        items = orangePrice;                // Will make input 'O' = to the price of oranges.
    }
    else if (input == 'P') {
        items = pearPrice;              // Will make input 'P' = to the price of pear.
    }
    else {
        items = -1;                 // Invalid ITEM!
    }


    if (items != -1) {                      // If the value of item is anything else than -1 the program will continue to code below.
        calculation = budget - items;
        if (calculation >= 0) {                         // Program will display purchase details if the value of calculation is equal or greater than 0.
            printf("Purchase was a success!\n");
            printf("Purchase details\n");
            printf("----------------------\n");
            printf("Item: %c\n", input);
            printf("Price: \x9C%d\n", items);
            printf("Remaining budget: \x9C%d\n\n", calculation);
            printf("Thanks for shopping with us!");
        }
        else {                                          // If the calculation will have a negative number it will make the purchase not possible.
            items = -1;
        }
    }
    if (items == -1) {                                  // If user inputs wrong item prefix or budget will be too low for purchase the program will execute following purchase failed code.
        printf("Purchase FAILED!\n");
        printf("Low budget or invalid item!\n\n");
        printf("Thanks for shopping with us!");
    }

    return 0;
};

int getItemPrice(int applePrice, int orangePrice, int pearPrice)
{
    printf("Welcome to the store. Please enter the prices for the following products: \n");
    printf("Please enter the price for the Orange: \x9C");
    scanf_s("%d", &orangePrice);                                        // Requests shopkeeper to enter price for for orange variable
    printf("Please enter the price for the Apple: \x9C");
    scanf_s("%d", &applePrice);                                     // Reqeustes shopkeeper to enter price for apple variable
    printf("Please enter the price for the Pear: \x9C");
    scanf_s("%d", &pearPrice);                                      // Requests shopkeeper to enter price for pear variable
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}

int displayMenu(int applePrice, int orangePrice, int pearPrice) {
    printf("**** Shop Menu ****\n");
    printf("Item:\t\tPrice\n");
    printf("A:\t\t\x9C%d\n", applePrice);                           // Displays price previously assigned by shopkeeper to the apple variable
    printf("O:\t\t\x9C%d\n", orangePrice);                          // Displays price previously assigned by shopkeeper to the orange variable
    printf("P:\t\t\x9C%d\n", pearPrice);                                // Displays price previously assigned by shopkeeper to the pear variable
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

What I have tried till this point that seems to resolve this issue is changing the values within int main to either initialise them by using:

```
orangePrice = 1;
applePrice = 1;
pearPrice = 1;
```

But then When I try running the program, the functions work and there are no issues when trying to compile the program. But the values in displayMenu function show all prices to be £1 and not the values that I have set in the getItemPrice function.

I have also tried playing with the return values in the function itself but did not have any success with that either.

What am I missing? I tried looking through the internet to find any kind of solutions but none helped so far.

Comment: Arguments to functions are passed *by value*. This means that the value of the argument will be *copied* and the function will only have the copied value. Modifying the copied value will not change the original value used when calling the function. Please do some research about *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `getItemPrice`, you're reading values into local variables.  Those changes aren't visible outside of the function.  You need to change the function's parameters to be pointers:

```
int getItemPrice(int *applePrice, int *orangePrice, int *pearPrice)
{
    printf("Welcome to the store. Please enter the prices for the following products: \n");
    printf("Please enter the price for the Orange: \x9C");
    scanf_s("%d", orangePrice);                                        // Requests shopkeeper to enter price for for orange variable
    printf("Please enter the price for the Apple: \x9C");
    scanf_s("%d", applePrice);                                     // Reqeustes shopkeeper to enter price for apple variable
    printf("Please enter the price for the Pear: \x9C");
    scanf_s("%d", pearPrice);                                      // Requests shopkeeper to enter price for pear variable
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And pass in the addresses of the variables you want to update:

```
getItemPrice(&applePrice, &orangePrice, &pearPrice);
```

Comment: I have been getting compiler warning level 1 after using your solution. But I have managed to fix it by changing the declaration of the function to the pointer as well. So as well as changing the function parameters also changing the declaration to.  int getItemPrice(int *applePrice, int *orangePrice, int *pearPrice)

Comment: @adek yes, in general unless you really know what you are doing and/or doing something really specific function declaration and implementation should always have the same signature